# Can Android WebView analyse <video> label in HTML5?

Tags: android, html

I am trying to write a sample android program to read an epub file which is embedded video,but I am not sure whether WebView can work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that android only starts with html5 by default at ICS? I could be wrong but you would probably need to get some OS stuff and work from there, maybe look into opera or dolphin browser, not sure if they have source code available but just along those lines, you need to find a OS browser with HTML5